# Using ARRAY_AGG() with all null values in input

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select distinct values of columns for each user in my table (in Google BigQuery). I've thought about using `ARRAY_AGG()` like:

```
SELECT user_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field1) AS f1, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field2) AS f2
FROM t GROUP BY user_id
```

But because for some `user_id`s all values in `field1` or `field2` are null, I get this error message: `Array 'f1' cannot have a null element`

I wonder if there is a workaround to avoid this error or maybe a different way to achieve the result without using `ARRAY_AGG()`

Comment: You may also be interested in https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=587 (it applies to `ARRAY_AGG` as well). I made some progress on the feature but don't have anything to announce yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-types#array-type

> BigQuery raises an error if query result has ARRAYs which contain NULL
>   elements, although such ARRAYs can be used inside the query.

your query is ok in a temporary query but not ok in end query result; so a workaround is you may define your query as a tmp table and filter out NULL values before giving end results:

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT user_id,
                    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field1) AS f1,
                    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field2) AS f2
FROM t GROUP BY user_id)

SELECT user_id,
    ARRAY(SELECT el FROM UNNEST(f1) AS el WHERE el IS NOT NULL) AS f1,
    ARRAY(SELECT el FROM UNNEST(f2) AS el WHERE el IS NOT NULL) AS f2
 FROM tmp
```

I've met same problems when porting over some Postgres SQL into BigQuery, a more elegant solution is FILTER clause on aggregation functions,

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html

like `ARRAY_AGG(f1 FILTER WHEN f1 IS NOT NULL)` which is not available in BigQuery which I really hope they can implement it

Comment: I have a feature request open for IGNORE NULLS with `ARRAY_AGG` and other aggregate and analytic functions if you are interested: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=587. The syntax would be something like `ARRAY_AGG(field1 IGNORE NULLS) AS f1`.

Answer (score 14):

BigQuery finally implemented [suggestion](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905693) from [Elliott Brossard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845090/using-array-agg-with-all-null-values-in-input#comment-67006476) and now you can do:

```sql
SELECT user_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field1 IGNORE NULLS) AS f1, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field2 IGNORE NULLS) AS f2
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT user_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field1) AS f1
  FROM t WHERE field1 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY user_id
),
t2 AS (
  SELECT user_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field2) AS f2
  FROM t WHERE field2 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT t1.user_id, f1, f2
FROM t1 FULL JOIN t2 
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

**When you run into nulls using ARRAY_AGG(), specify IGNORE NULLS:**

> IGNORE NULLS or RESPECT NULLS: If IGNORE NULLS is specified, the NULL
> values are excluded from the result. If RESPECT NULLS or if neither is
> specified, the NULL values are included in the result. An error is
> raised if an array in the final query result contains a NULL element.

From: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg

**Working example using IGNORE NULLS:**

```sql
SELECT
    category, 
    array_agg(fruit IGNORE NULLS) as fruits_array,
FROM (SELECT "A" as category, NULL as fruit UNION ALL
      SELECT "B" as category, "apple" as fruit UNION ALL
      SELECT "B" as category, "pear" as fruit UNION ALL
      SELECT "C" as category, "orange" as fruit)
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY category
```